# MVC Pass Paramater from ActionLink to View to return Recordset

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5, html.actionlink, request.querystring

I would like to pass a value from a link to a View and display the fields of the single record on the page.

Lets say I have `@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Article/"+@item.ID, "News")` which outputs /News/Article/1, I would need a Controller called NewsController with a /News/Article View.

I already have the following:

NewsController:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class NewsController : Controller
    {
        private WebApplication1Entities db = new WebApplication1Entities();
        public ActionResult Article()
        {
            var articleModel = (from m in db.News where (m.Id == 1) && (m.Active == true) select m);
            return View(articleModel);
        }
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult LatestNews()
        {
            var latestModel = (from m in db.News where (m.Id != 1) && (m.Active == true) select m);
            return View(latestModel);
        }

}
```

Not sure if I should use FirstOrDefault() as it can only be one record as the Id is unique, but unsure how to reference item objects inside the View without an IEnumerable list. At present the Id is set to 1 but I would like the recordset to reflect the Id passed.

Not sure what code to put inside the View, Article though, here is what I have so far:

Article.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.News>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    ViewBag.Title = @item.Title;   

    <div class="row">
        <article class="span9 maxheight">
            <section class="block-indent-1 divider-bot-2">
                <h2>@item.Title</h2>
                @item.Summary
                @item.Content
            </section>
        </article>
        <article class="span3 divider-left maxheight">
            <section class="block-indent-1">
                <h2>Latest News</h2>
                @{ Html.RenderAction("LatestNews", "News"); }
            </section>
        </article>
    </div>
}
```

LatestNews.cshtml

```
@{ Layout = null; }
@model IEnumerable<Shedtember.Models.News>

<ul class="nav sf-menu clearfix">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.MenuLink(item.Title, "Article/"@item.ID, "News")
    }
</ul>
```

This works for Id 1 but this needs to be dynamic.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your RouteConfig class map a route as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute("Article", "Article/{id}", new {controller = "News", action = "Article"});
```

then in your Article method you can add and use the id parameter as follows:

```
    public ActionResult Article(int id)
    {
        var articleModel = (from m in db.News where (m.Id == id) && (m.Active == true) select m);
        return View(articleModel);
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to mask /News/Article/1 as /News/Hero-Hour or /News/Article/2 as /News/Friendly-Fire using a more seo friendly url structure?

Comment: Are you using IIS7 or above? Also are the list of articles fairly fixed? If so you could use a URL rewriting tool. Not something I've done myself but the following article looks easy to follow: [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Comment: I'm developing on IIS Express through Visual Studio 2013, not sure what IIS is being used on the remote hosting environment.

Comment: If performance isn't an issue then you could change your Article method to accept an article name rather than Id, and then query the DB based on the name. Would be slower though (even with an index) and probably not the best solution, but all I can think of at the moment.

Comment: Performance should always be a important factor, granted the db is small at the moment but would still like to keep it efficient, thank you.